# Using python functions to return and compare

Tags: python, function, compare, return

```
def main():
 port = 10000000
 portChecked = portChecker(port)
 if portChecked is portChecked:
  print '%d is in the portlist' % port

def portChecker(x):
 portCheck = range(65565)
 portList = list(portCheck)
 portCast = x

 if portCast in portList:
  return
 else:
  print '%d is not in the list' % portCast

if __name__ == '__main__':main()
```

Starting to learn python, with the violent python ebook, thought I'd write a simple function to check ports that are being inputted by the user(or by static value)

If the port is within the range, the program will print out the %d is in the list, but like here, if it is outside the range, both print statements will execute.

Am I missing something with function calls, use of return statements or am I looking at this in the wrong way.

Googling, doesn't seem to give similar solutions, most tutorials use int's or strings.

All help is appreciated.

Comment: `if portChecked is portChecked:` will always be true

Comment: Creating a whole list of 65565 integers just to check if a number is in an interval is just wrong. use this: `if 0 < x <= 65565`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few problems with your code:

- `portChecker` always returns `None`
- `portChecked is portChecked` always evaluates to `True`
- generally it's not a good idea to have (part of) your output inside the check function

Try something like this:

```
def checkPort(x):
    portList = range(65565)
    return x in portList

port = 10000
if checkPort(port):
    print '%d is in the port list' % port
else:
    print '%d is NOT in the list' % port
```

Also, note that ports are [from 1 to 65565](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_numbers#Technical_details), so you should rather check whether it's in `range(1, 65565 + 1)`. However, unless you plan to check whether the port is already reserved or such, it's faster and much clearer just to check whether `1 <= x <= 65565`.

Comment: I'm using argparse from another function to pass down the port value. Thought I'd use this form instead of copying the whole script. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why this isn't mentioned yet.

You do not need to create list of values (integers) to check whether some value in this range.
You could just write:

```
def check_port(port):
    return 0 <= port <= 65565
```

Comment: Actually, I _did_ mention that (but just in passing), but it's good you stress that part a bit. ;-)

Comment: Btw, I wonder if OP is aware that `range(65565)` does not contain `65565`.

Comment: AH, that looks a lot simpler, it's my first language, didn't realize you could use return like that.